# ellipitic operator on  compact complex manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be compact complex manifold and Define part of Kodaria-Spancer operator

$$
\tilde{E}_t：=\partial\bar{\partial}\bar{\partial}^{*}\partial^{*}
$$

on $\Lambda^{p,p+1}(X)$

Question :Does the $\tilde{E}$ strong ellipitic partial differential operator?

Comment: Why don't you compute the principal symbol?  This should be an useful exercise for you to do.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that a small deformation of a Kahler manifold is Kahler? You may want to take a look at Micher Schweitzer's "Autour de la cohomologie de Bott-Chern" http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3528 where he gives a slightly more "believable" operator that does the same job as Kodaira-Spencer's one.

Comment: Definitely right Gunnar! 